# php spl autoload register problems

Tags: php

These codes  are copied from the book << Pro php mvc >>,I think they miss some lines,there are

```
$flags = PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY | PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE;
```

but no **preg_split**

and I can't figure out  the line

```
$file = strtolower(str_replace("\\", DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, trim($class, "\\"))).".php";
```

it trimed **double back slashes** first,then try to replace **double back slashes** with **DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR** ,how??

What circumstance it will have **double back slashes** in a  class name?

the codes:

=------

```
function autoload($class)
{
    $paths = explode(PATH_SEPARATOR, get_include_path());

    $flags = PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY | PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE;
    $file = strtolower(str_replace("\\", DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, trim($class, "\\"))).".php";

    foreach ($paths as $path)
    {
        $combined = $path.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$file;

        if (file_exists($combined))
        {
            include($combined);
            return;
        }
    }

    throw new Exception("{$class} not found");
}

class Autoloader
{
    public static function autoload($class)
    {
        autoload($class);
    }

}

spl_autoload_register('autoload');
spl_autoload_register(array('autoloader', 'autoload'));
```

Comment: Those are backslashes, not forward slashes. In the first example you have three backslashes, in the second you have two. Which is correct? The first backslash is in either case an [escape character](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.escape.php).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In PHP namespaces are delimitered with a backslash as you can see in the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.rationale.php):

> $c = new \my\name\MyClass; // see "Global Space" section

When you see the pattern uses *two* backslashes, this is because a backlash itself has a special meaning, namely as an escape character, as you again can see in the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.escape.php).

> In particular, if you want to match a backslash, you write "\\".

So in order to match the backslash you need to escape it, and end up with two backslashes.

Comment: I corrected misspellings.Thanks,Do these codes miss preg_split?

Comment: What do you mean by that? Also, you `$flags` variable is left unused.

Comment: Yeah,I wonder why $flags is not be used.       PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY is for preg_split,so I think the codes miss preg_split.

Answer (score 1):

The line with the $flags is probably left over from a previous way they wrote the class loader and was forgotten to be removed.

The **back slashes**(!) aren't actually double. Back slashes function as an escape character in PHP and many other languages. For example you can write quotes in a quote limited string like so:

```
$someString = "Hello, so called \"World\"!";
```

Without the quote before World ending the string and the rest of the line causing a parse error.

But to write the escape character into a string it has to be escaped itself. So you actually just have single back slashes.

Replacing back slashes with DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR (\ on Windows, / on Linux/Unix) is a convenient way of organizing your code in a way very similar to Java packages.

Back slashes in PHP indicate namespaces, so your class might be something like:

```
\jacob\someproject\SomeClass
```

Do the replacements and (on Linux) you can map that to a relative path:

```
jacob/someproject/someclass.php
```

Personally I'd remove the strtolower, so you can keep the camel case in the file name:

```
jacob\someproject\SomeClass.php
```